# Inputting into an array using scanner class (error: incompatible types: Scanner cannot be converted to String)

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to input student details using a scanner but I keep getting this error:

```
error: incompatible types: Scanner cannot be converted to String
```

I have 4 scanners which are

```
static Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner Date = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner address = new Scanner(System.in);
static Scanner gender = new Scanner(System.in);
```

My code is as follows

```
System.out.println("You have chosen to add a student. Please enter the following details");
System.out.println("Name: ");
String Name = name.nextLine();  
System.out.println("DOB: ");
String DOB = Date.nextLine();
System.out.println("Address: ");
String Address = address.nextLine();
System.out.println("Gender: ");
String Gender = gender.nextLine();

app.addStudent(name, DOB, address, gender);
System.out.println(Name + " has been added!" + "\n" + "Returning to menu....");

app.delay();
```

The `addStudent` method is as follows

```
public void addStudent (String name,String DOB,String address,String gender)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < enrolment.length; i++)
    {
        if (enrolment[i] == null)
        {
            this.enrolment[size] = new Student(name, DOB, address, gender);
            this.size++;

            if (gender == "Male")
            { 
                this.maleStudents++;
            }
            else { 
                this.femaleStudents++; 
            }
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You only need one scanner.

Comment: You should read up on Scanners first: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

Answer (score 6):

The problem is that you're passing your `Scanner` objects to your `addStudent` method instead of the strings that you obtained from the scanners:

```
app.addStudent(name, DOB, address, gender);
```

Should be

```
app.addStudent(Name, DOB, Address, Gender);
```

Also:

- one `Scanner` object should be sufficient. No need for four of them.
- Java code conventions dictate that variable names are in lower camel-case, i.e. `gender` instead of `Gender`.

---

Putting everything together, your code should look something like this:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("You have chosen to add a student. Please enter the following details");

System.out.println("Name: ");
String name = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("DOB: ");
String dob = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Address: ");
String address = scanner.nextLine();

System.out.println("Gender: ");
String gender = scanner.nextLine();

app.addStudent(name, dob, address, gender);

System.out.println(name + " has been added!" + "\n" + "Returning to menu....");
```

Answer (score 1):

You only need one scanner, not one for each input.

In you code you are confusing `Name` (the string) with `name` (the scanner).

This is why there are naming rules.

Try changing to

```
 Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

 String name = input.nextLine ();
 String gender = input.nextLine (); 
 ...
```

then

```
 app.addStudent (name, dob, address, gender);
```

try also reading about [naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Answer (score 0):

name, adress, and gender are scanners, your method takes Strings

```
app.addStudent(Name, DOB, Address, Gender);
```

is the method with the String variables that you defined